# ngRepeat $last when repeater is bound with no items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently using the following code to create a directive which does something whenever data is re-bound to an ng-repeat

```
myModule.directive('tableLoaded', function($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA', 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            if (scope.$last) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    // DO something
                });
            }
        }
    }

});
```

I've seen this code several times on SO and it works perfectly, until the repeater is empty, because there is no "last" item. I've looked for any kind of event I can hook into to fire something whenever a repeater is bound with no items but I've drawn a blank.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Can use things like `ng-if="!dataItems.length"` to display `"no results"` for example. Or use `$watch` to check if array is empty

Comment: this feels like an anti-pattern.  you should not be tying your application logic to a specific HTML state.  There are other ways to fire functions whenever your data changes;  firing a function whenever something is drawn in HTML isn't the best option in angular.  You should be programming against your data, not your view state (in almost all cases).  This is of course a generalization, without knowing what the function is actually doing, it's not reasonable to present an alternative.

Comment: I agree with @Claies. Using `$last` is convenient for very specialized dom manipulation  that requires collections of elements to exist before firing but the reverse (no elements) is usually not the case as there are numerous ways to let angular change the dom based on data model

Comment: Thanks guys, the reason I'm using $last is becuase the repeater is creating an HTML table and every time the model changes and the table is recreated I need to loop through the table cells and record column widths and row heights so that I can resize the header and fixed left hand column.

I've been trying to think of a way to use your suggestion of ng-if="!dataItems.length" in combination with $last to fire the function every time the data changes, but wait for the HTML to be created if length > 0. I assume the watch would fire first and the $last would always fire afterwards?

Comment: In which case, I could fire the function when the model changes (only if length === 0) but if length > 0 I would make it wait until $last has fired. That seems like a good solution but something is telling me that they would both happen at the end of the current digest cycle, not necessarily in the order I'm expecting.